# Write <script> or other tags as text in html

Tags: javascript

i want this javascript code to write to a < p > the tag < script> as text any solution:

```
document.getElementById('tests').innerHTML += 
    "<input type='radio'><label for='contactChoice3'><"+"script></label>";
```

Comment: Use HTML entities? Angle brackets have meaning in html.

Comment: Use `.textContent` instead of `.innerHTML`.